# Issue with linking css & js files on Github

Tags: github

I'm hosting a site/page on Github, however, it is only reading the index.html file and not applying the css or js files to the site. I'm listing the file path for both the css and js files in a relative format (develop/style.css & develop/script.js) - I've tried reformatting this multiple times and have friend quite a few threads on stack overflow, nothing seems to be working :(. Can anyone find the missing link? Here's a link to the Github repo: https://github.com/emblair96/HW3-password-generator (it's an assignment for a coding Bootcamp I'm in -- so this is all very new to me).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The `src` tag is case sensitive. Your folder is `Develop` with a capital "D," but your HTML `src` tags both use `develop` with a lowercase "d."

Comment: Wow, yep that was it.  Thanks so much for your help!